# How do I remove rows in a list containing numpy arrays based on a condition?

Tags: python, list, numpy, list-comprehension

I have the following numpy array `arr_split`:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1.,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

arr_split = np.array_split(arr1,
                           indices_or_sections = 4,
                           axis = 0)

arr_split
```

Output:

```
[array([[1., 2., 3.]]),
 array([[4., 5., 6.]]),
 array([[7., 8., 9.]]),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)]
```

How do I remove rows which are "empty" (ie. in the above eg., it's the last row). The array `arr_split` can have any number of "empty" rows. The above eg. just so happens to have only one row which is "empty".

I have tried using list comprehension, as per below:

```
arr_split[[(arr_split[i].shape[0] != 0) for i in range(len(arr_split))]]
```

but this doesn't work because the list comprehension `[(arr_split[i].shape[0] != 0) for i in range(len(arr_split))]` part returns a list, when I actually just need the elements in the list to feed into `arr_split[]` as indices.

Anyone know how I could fix this or is there another way of doing this? If possible, looking for the easiest way of doing this without too many loops or if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through and check the size. Only add them to the new list if they have a size greater than 0.

```
arr_split_new = [arr for arr in arr_split if arr.size > 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can change the `indices_or_sections` value to length of the first axis, this will prevent any empty arrays from being produced

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1.,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

arr_split = np.array_split(arr1,
                           indices_or_sections = arr1.shape[0],
                           axis = 0)

arr_split

>>> [
    array([[1., 2., 3.]]),
    array([[4., 5., 6.]]),
    array([[7., 8., 9.]])
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Hammad. This doesn't quite work for what I want to do because `indices_or_sections` is a user specified value in my algorithm, so I want this to be flexible. The above example I have given is just a minimal working example.

Comment: @Leockl try replacing it with `min( user_val, arr1.shape[0])` this way the indices specified will not be more than the number of elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate to get the indexes and size to check if empty

`indexes = [idx for idx, v in enumerate(arr_split) if v.size != 0]`

`[0, 1, 2]`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work because the returned indexes are in a list